# Right-floating element display gets messed up in Chrome after resizing the window?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have an element in my site's footer that's floated to the right, and it works great, except that in Chrome, when I resize the window, I have certain styling that sets the display to block without floats (check out the example [here](http://antonpug.com/)), but problem is, when I resize the window back to large size, even though float:right is applied, the element appears below other elements in the footer. The weird thing is...unchecking the float:right style and checking it again in inspector returns the element to its normal position. Anyone know what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Its likely that your twitter link is causing some weird things, if you dont mind your hosted in cali text above the rest you could move it to be the first element in the  tag and that will fix your re-size issue.

Or since it looks like you are using twitter bootstraps grid you can just use their class like:

```
<footer class="container" role="footer" style="display: block;">
    <span id="copyright" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 text-left">©2013 Anton Pugachevsky</span>
    <span id="social" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 text-center">
        <a href="http://twitter.com/antonpug">
            <img src="http://antonpug.com/wp-content/uploads/twitter-social-icon.png" />
        </a>
    </span>
    <span id="random-blurb" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 text-left">Hosted with ♥ in California</span>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use *text-align: right;* on parent element and use only *float:left;* on child elements where needed or use other type of alignment.

It is more a workaround, but not the solution. This problem appears to be some kind of chrome style refresh bug, as reaplying float style or refreshing page solves this.